# How do you pull a single attribute out of an array of hashes?

Tags: ruby

I would like to know ice cream preferences of all my cats in an array.

So the output would be just the `:ice_cream` out of all the `cat`'s :

```
[ "vanilla", "chocolate", "mint chocolate", "mice" ]
```

While the cat objects are :

```
cat => {:ice_cream => "chocolate", :paws => "4", :wants_to_kill_humans => "yes" }
```

Yikes this is such an easy answer I bet, but I can't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want something like:

```
@cats.collect {|cat| cat[:ice_cream] }
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much Ben! I can't believe i couldn't figure this out. Thanks so much.

Comment: strange.. that groups all the params together as one giant word. do you have to use gsub to seperate them into arrays?